# How to insert into a SQL table using a for-loop in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, node.js, for-loop

I am having trouble finding the proper SQL syntax on adding items to my table using a for loops and an array. This is what I am trying to do:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: 'DUSAgeocodeDB'
});

var addreses = ['addres1', 'address2', 'address3'];
var latitude = [12, 45, 789];
var longitude = [987, 654, 321];

for (var i =0; i <addreses.length; i++) {

    con.connect(function(err) {
        con.query(`INSERT INTO maintable (mainaddress, latitude, longitude) VALUES (${addreses[i]}, ${latitude[i]}, ${longitude[i]} )`, function (err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;

            console.log('VALUES ADDED')
        });

    })
}
```

What would be the proper syntax on the con.query() statement in order to save those values to mysql table? This is something else that I've tried but it does not work

```
for (var i =0; i <addreses.length; i++) {

    con.connect(function(err) {
        con.query("INSERT INTO maintable (mainaddress, latitude, longitude) VALUES ("+${mysql.escape(addreses[i])}+", "+${mysql.escape(latitude[i])}+", "+${mysql.escape(longitude[i])}" )", function (err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;

            console.log('VALUES ADDED')
        });

    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest leveraging [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) this way you can fire multiple async operations off in parallel. mysql does not come with promise support, however, you could use [msql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) that does. Here I have wrapped the existing `con.query` in its own promise.

```
function queryPromise(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(query, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

con.connect(async (err) => {
    await Promise.all(
        addreses.map((_, i) => {
            return queryPromise(
                `INSERT INTO maintable (mainaddress, latitude, longitude) VALUES (${addreses[i]}, ${latitude[i]}, ${longitude[i]} )`
            );
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did implement this into my code!

Comment: @CarlosVides you are welcome, don't forget to mark the response as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

you could write

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: 'DUSAgeocodeDB'
});

var addreses = ['addres1', 'address2', 'address3'];
var latitude = [12, 45, 789];
var longitude = [987, 654, 321];

con.connect(function(err) { // create a single connection to execute all the queries
   for (let i=0; i < addreses.length; i++) { //use let instead of var to prevent issues with closures in asynchronous code
      con.query(`INSERT INTO maintable (mainaddress, latitude, longitude) VALUES (${addreses[i]}, ${latitude[i]}, ${longitude[i]} )`, function (err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('VALUES ADDED')
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, this did not work I keep getting                                Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'addres1' in 'field list', I do have followed your suggestion about creating only one connection! Thank you so much